# Do I need to manually destroy a session on Shopify app uninstall?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I'm using the shopify_app gem.

The issue occurs when I install my app, then uninstall, then try to re-install. I am redirected from the app Oauth login page to my logged-in shop with a "app not found" message.

This leads me to believe that maybe session data is not being destroyed when the app is uninstalled, but I'm not sure how to fix this. I assume that I don't need a webhook to destroy a session.

Can you spot anything wrong in my setup?

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  scope '/hooks', :controller => :hooks do
    post :new_customer_callback
    post :app_uninstalled_callback
  end


  root :to => 'home#index'
  mount ShopifyApp::Engine, at: '/'

end



class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include ShopifyApp::SessionsController
end


class AuthenticatedController < ApplicationController
  before_action :login_again_if_different_shop
  around_filter :shopify_session
  layout ShopifyApp.configuration.embedded_app? ? 'embedded_app' : 'application'
  helper_method :current_shop
end
```

shopify_session_repository.rb

```
if Rails.configuration.cache_classes
  ShopifyApp::SessionRepository.storage = 'Shop'
else
  ActionDispatch::Reloader.to_prepare do
    ShopifyApp::SessionRepository.storage = 'Shop'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an idea. Could it be that you are not updating your access token when you are re-installing your app?

This is because when you uninstall the access token is no longer valid and your app could still be trying to use the old access token in your db.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this was the answer!